# how does HDR worked, how to make HDR effect

Tags: image-processing, hdrimages, hdr

I had read a blog [Histogram Equalization for Image Enhancement](http://www.cromwell-intl.com/3d/histogram/) which gives 7 steps to convert normal images to a HDR image (below).
It's said that a C/C++ program for histogram equalization can easily written using the Open Computer Vision Library or OpenCV. The major steps of such a program include:

1. Read the input image. This can be in most any image format thanks to OpenCV. This input image contains `n` pixels: `n = height × width`
2. Convert from RGB (curiously stored in the order blue, green, red by OpenCV) to HSV: Hue, Saturation, and Value.
3. Calculate the histogram of the input image. This is a 256 value array, where `H[x]` contains the number of pixels with value `x`.
4. Calculate the cumulative density function of the histogram. This is a 256 value array, where `cdf[x]` contains the number of pixels with value `x` or less:
   `cdf[x] = H[0] + H[1] + H[2] + ... + H[x]`
5. Loop through the `n` pixels in the entire image and replace the value at each `i`'th point: `V[i] <-- floor(255*(cdf[V[i]] - cdf[0])/(n - cdf[0]))`
6. Convert the image back from HSV to RGB.
7. Save the image in the desired format and file name.

At step 3, I do not understand what `H[x]` is? Does `x` refer to the R, G, B, or H, S, or V values? Also, at step 5 what the meaning of the value `i`?

Comment: This is just an histogram equalization algorithm, nothing to do with real HDR imaging.

Answer (score 2):

**First Question:**

H(x) is the histogram of the image.

A histogram of a digital image with intensity levels in the range [0, 255] is a discrete function h(r_k) = n_k, where r_k is the kth intensity value and n_k is the number of pixels in the image with intensity r_k.

From: Digital Image Processing Third Edition by Gonzalez / Woods page 120

**Second question: what is i?**

i is the variable looping over the picture.

Comment: thank you very much
With your help I have calculated the histogram already
[IMG]http://t1.qpic.cn/mblogpic/816e11b21ea928198bce/2000[IMG]
now how to convert "V[i] <-- floor(255*(cdf[V[i]] - cdf[0])/(n - cdf[0]))"
to C++ code
thank you!

Comment: It's an assignment. You can replace `<--` with `=`

Comment: @stonexing could you please provide me the code for the HDR effect.